# How can i update the array when one of my variable is update?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

How can i update the array of boolean (choosing) and int (number) when the variable N is update in the costructor of my class?

```
public class Lamport_Algorithm implements Runnable {
private static int N = 0;

private static boolean choosing[] = new boolean[N];
private static int number[] = new int[N];
private final int idProcess;

public Lamport_Algorithm(int idProcess) {
    this.idProcess = idProcess;

    if (N == 0) {
        N = 1;
    } else {
        N += 1;
    }
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Hello" + "[" + idProcess + "]" + " There are: " + N + " Thread ");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        System.out.println(choosing[i]);
    }
} }
```

This is the Main:

```
public class MainTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Lamport_Algorithm a = new Lamport_Algorithm(1);         
        Thread T1 = new Thread (a);         
        T1.start();    
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is a main reason not to use parallel arrays. Use a reference array of type that holds an int and boolean, and avoid duplication of information.

Comment: In other words : don't use static for your fields. And then read about Java naming conventions and stop using the _ char.

Comment: Also note that you can just do N += 1. No need for the if/else.  Zero plus one is one, after all.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize both arrays inside the constructor like below.

**Your full version of code.**

```
class Lamport_Algorithm implements Runnable {
private static int N = 0;

private static boolean choosing[];
private static int number[];
private final int idProcess;

public Lamport_Algorithm(int idProcess) {
    this.idProcess = idProcess;

    if (N == 0) {
        N = 1;
    } else {
        N += 1;
    }

    choosing = new boolean[N];
    number = new int[N];
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Hello" + "[" + idProcess + "]" + " There are: " + N + " Thread ");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        System.out.println(choosing[i]);
    }
}
}

class MainTest {
public static void main(String[] args){

    Lamport_Algorithm a = new Lamport_Algorithm(1);
    Thread T1 = new Thread (a);
    T1.start();
}
}
```